# List.Sort by Substring in PowerQuery (M)

Tags: list, sorting, powerquery

I have a list of strings I'm trying to sort:

List

- F20
- S20
- S21
- F21

I would like my sort to result as below: by the 2 digit number first, then the 1 character letter. However, I can't create a static order for the sort because the strings will update/change over time:

List

- S20
- F20
- S21
- F21

Is there a List.Sort syntax/property in PowerQuery M I can use to sort by substrings within a list? If not, is there any elegant way of accomplishing this without a static list order?

Comment: Do you want F20 above S20 or below ?

Comment: @AnmolParida - I would like S to before F.

Comment: That would take some explicit coding. On it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a custom comparator and pass it as a second arg to List.Sort. Here is code, assuming that each item has only **1** letter

```
let
    list = {"F20", "S20", "S21", "F21"},
    transform = (value) => Text.Range(value, 1) & Text.Range(value, 0, 1)
in
    List.Sort(list, (a, b) => Value.Compare(transform(a), transform(b)))
```

results in
F20
S20
F21
S21

Comment: You're wonderful, Sasha. Many thanks for the support - I'm going to test further.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using `keys`

```
inputList = ['F20', 'S20', 'F21', 'S21']

sortedList = sorted(inputList, key=lambda item: item[0:1], reverse=True)
sortedList = sorted(sortedList, key=lambda item: item[1:])
print(sortedList)
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this syntax in PowerQuery - is this actually Python?

Comment: This is python.  you cn use ```key``` . 
 Refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: Apologies, I had requested PowerQuery M support - are you saying there's a way to implement Python in the M dialogue? Frankly, I'd rather keep the script in M if possible.